# Subscribe Observable<Type>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Subscribe to Observable:

```
checkAllowEmail(control: FormControl) {
    this.userService.getUserByEmail(control.value)
     .subscribe((user: UserDto) => {
       console.log(user);
       if (user !== undefined) {
         console.log(this.isAllowEmail);
         this.isAllowEmail = false;
         console.log(this.isAllowEmail);
       }
     });
  }
```

Return Observable from method:

```
getUserByEmail(email: string): Observable<UserDto> {
    return this.http.get(`http://localhost:9092/api/v1/users?email=${email}`)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .map((user: UserDto) => user ? user : undefined);
  }
```

Class UserDto:

```
export class UserDto {
  constructor(
    public email: string,
    public name: string,
    public role: string
  ) {}
}
```

Response from BE-side:

```
{"name":"art","email":"art@mail.ru","role":"user"}
```

Why I can change variable isAllowEmail to false in if statement in checkAllowEmail method?

Comment: Can you see those two `console.log`s?

Comment: what does this: `console.log(user);` log?

Comment: @standby954  No, nothing

Comment: @Ferus7 It is check user object

Comment: Nothing? Are you sure you're receiving data? You should consider adding breakpoints to your code and debugging it.

Comment: @bsuart i mean, what does it write on the log, the values

Comment: @Ferus7 nothing

Comment: add some `console.logs` in `getUserByEmail`

Comment: Then, as I said, either you're not receiving data form the server, or there is a problem in one of the operators you're applying to the observable. Consider debugging or adding an error callback to the `subscribe` function to know whether there is an error somewhere

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you still have to use the map function, when using the HttpClient (since angular version 4). Try using

```
getUserByEmail(email: string): Observable<UserDto> {
    return this.http.get<UserDto>(`http://localhost:9092/api/v1/users?email=${email}`);
}
```

Else use something like Postman or even curl from the console to verify that you api returns the correct/expected responses.

Also check if you use 'use strict'; in that case `this` will refere to the callable you pass to the subscribe method and not the surrounding component class.